OnMessageAttachmentsChanged is not working expected in outlook
// Added to the manifest file
     <LaunchEvent Type="OnMessageAttachmentsChanged" FunctionName="onMessageAttachmentChangeHandler"         SendMode="PromptUser" />

// Code to trigger when users add or remove attachments
export const onMessageAttachmentChangeHandler = async (event: Office.AddinCommands.Event) => {
    console.log("Attachment changed in the message:", event);
    event.completed({ allowEvent: true });
};

// Included in events.ts for event registration
Office.actions.associate('onMessageAttachmentChangeHandler', onMessageAttachmentChangeHandler);


When I run this add-in with the above condition, then the problem which is coming is when I am uploading anything then it fires trigger and this is what is coming
[DuplicatedName] Function=onMessageAttachmentChangeHandler
Am I doing something wrong here??
